# Multiple Sub Queries from the same Table

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, subquery, row-number

Using SQL in pyspark, I'm having trouble piecing together the logic for having multiple select statements using the same table:

- Select statement for choosing the needed columns
- Select statement for row ranking the data by time
- Select statement to choose row rank = 2

for all from the same table.

Is there a simple to implement this logic? I tried connecting the 3 select statements by using **WITH** and **UNION** but no luck so far.

Having the most trouble with calling the row rank column for my **WHERE** clause considering the variable isn't found in the table.

Here is a rough draft to get the picture (easiest way to give an example):

```
SELECT * FROM
-- First select statement
(
SELECT colA, colB FROM tableA
-- Second select statement
(
SELECT time, responsetime,
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time desc, responsetime desc) AS row_rank 
FROM TableA
) 
-- Third select statement
select row_rank from tableA
where row_rank = 2
) T1
```

As always, thank you if you can offer any help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
WITH t1 AS (

  SELECT id, time, responsetime, col4, col5, ..., colN FROM table1

)
, t2 AS (

  SELECT id, time, responsetime, col4, col5, ..., colN, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time desc, responsetime desc) AS row_rank FROM table1

)
SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE row_rank = 2;
```

Can be more simply be refactored to:

```
WITH t1 AS (

  SELECT id, time, responsetime, col4, col5, ..., colN, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time desc, responsetime desc) AS row_rank FROM t1

)
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE row_rank = 2;
```